# Magic number removal on ROT13 in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, magic-numbers, rot13, coldfusion-2018

I have this function that calculates ROT13.

```
string function rot13(required string inString) output="false"  {

  var j = 0;
  var k = 0;
  var out = "";
  for (var i = 1; i <= Len(arguments.inString); i++){
    j = asc(Mid(arguments.inString, i, 1));
    if(j >= asc("A") && j <= asc("Z")) {
        j = ((j - 52) % 26) + asc("A");
    }
    else if(j >= asc("a") && j <= asc("z")) {
        j = ((j - 84) % 26) + asc("a");
    }

    out &= Chr(j);
  } // end for

  return out;
}
```

I don't like that it appears to have 3 magic numbers 52, 26, and 84. I think the 26 can be replace with `asc("Z") - asc("A") + 1`

But I don't know what the 52 and 84 represent. I don't know what I would name them.

Comment: Is this for simple obfuscation? ROT13 doesn't really do much for security.

Comment: If you do double ROT13, it does twice as much security. Seriously, it is not really secure.

Comment: Also, you can remove `var k`. It's not being used.

Comment: Double ROT13 is ROT26 Which is plaintext. :-)

Comment: You could always just comment what these magic numbers mean. Since this is just a rotation cipher, it would just add more overhead to the function to variable-ize them.

Comment: Actually, you can also get rid of `var j = 0` also. It's being reset a few lines down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By looking at your magic numbers and an ASCII table, I came up with this.

26 is the number of letters in the alphabet.  That's your first magic number.

`asc('A')` is 65.  65 minus 13 is 52, your second magic number.

`asc('a')` is 97.  97 minus 13 is 84, your third magic number.

That's what the numbers represent.  You can decide how to name your variables.  Alternatively, you can add the explanation as a comment.

**Edit starts here**

13 is the number of characters you are rotating.  That's also a magic number.  You could enhance your function by making this an argument so you can rotate by other numbers as well.